# python syntax error can figure out!! variable

Tags: python

I have this code in python, to ask people how many cigarettes do they smoke and return how many they smoke in a month and in a year. I have an error at line 4, I have searched this but I don't find any that work. I know it is a syntax problem but I can't figure it out.

Here is the code:

```
print ("Hola, Que Tal")
print ("Como te llamas?")
miNumbre=input()
print ("Mucho Gusto " + miNumbre )
print ("Cuantos Paquetes de Puchos Fumas Por Dia?")
puchos=input()
print ("Fumas " +str(int(puchos) * 30) + " Paquetes de Puchos Por Mes")
print ("En Un Año Fumas " +str(int(puchos) * 360) + " Paquetes de Puchos")
```

Comment: What is the syntax error you are getting?

Comment: use `raw_input()` instead of `input()`.

Comment: Guess: `TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects` If so, it's saying you can't concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects. Convert the int to a str explicitly, use a format string, or use the print("string", int) version of print.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

and it's better to format the string like this when you have to use nums and chars:

```
print ("Mucho Gusto {}".format(miNumbre ))
```

Comment: The problem here is that you're just masking the fact that `input` is `eval`ing the input in Python2. This leaves behind a potentially dangerous bug

Answer (score 0):

It's really important to run this with Python3

```
miNumbre=input()
print ("Mucho Gusto " + miNumbre )
```

in Python2, `input()` evaluates the string, so miNumbre will be an int

If you mean to use Python2, the equivalent would be

```
miNumbre = raw_input()
print "Mucho Gusto " + miNumbre
```

Comment: Py3 doesn't give the listed error, ergo, he must be on Py2.

Comment: @TemporalWolf, I don't want to make assumptions about the OP's setup or which version of Python they are trying to learn, but it wouldn't be the first time someone has had both installed and not been aware which one is actually running their code.